# Is it possible to map/rename keys loaded from Azure App Configuration?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-app-configuration

I want to use both `appsettings.json` and Azure App Configuration to provide configuration for my application. Azure App Configuration will be used by several applications and it is going to be handled via prefixes like `AppName1:Auth:ApiKey`. However, part of this configuration will be kept in json file like

```json
"Auth" : {
   "Duration": "00:10:00"
}
```

As it is written here, these settings can't be fetched via single section as they have different key grouping:

- `AppName1:Auth` - Azure App Cofniguration
- `Auth` - appsettings.json

I would like to have this key grouping `AppName1:Auth` mapped to `Auth`, but I'm not sure how to handle this.

I knot that I can change appsettings.json file to

```json
"AppName1" : {
   "Auth" : {
      "Duration": "00:10:00"
   }
}
```

However, this is something what I want to avoid. And Azure App Configuration per application is also not a solution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a method to do this:

```cs
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
{
    builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options => options.TrimKeyPrefix("AppName1:"));
})
```

All credits to my workmate!